# JAVA Apache Jena Fuseki: Create Endpoint via API, Retrieve all endpoints via API

Tags: java, jena, fuseki

i have two questions related to Apache Jena Fuseki.
The first one is: 
I need to create an endpoint using the API (from java code, not from Fuseki UI). For "endpoint" i mean the dataset that fuseki allow to create using the UI, from http://localhost:xxxx/. I also need to make it persistent.
The second one:
consider that we have a list of dataset already created. I want to get the "label" of each existing endpoint (ex: dataset1, dataset56, testDataset ....).
I know how to query and update data from a specified endpoint, but i have no idea on how manage datasets (create/delete and also get the label).

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

EDIT1:

I've found a workaround
Retrieve dataset list by sending a GET request to http://localhost:3030/$/server

Create dataset by sending a POST request to http://localhost:3030/$/datasets
The following POST parameters must be set: "dbName=/dataseName&dbType=tdb"

dbType can be set either to mem (non persistent dataset) or tdb (persistent dataset).

Still trying to find a way to get the same results using a Jena API call.